# Any command line tool to convert "black-and-white" images to "bit mapped"("two-tone") images

Tags: bitmap, grayscale, linux

On Windows, IrfanView can create a bi-level version of **Gray Level Images** conveniently.

Is there any command line tool available on Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have to install `imagemagick`
2. Try:

   `convert image1.jpg -colorspace Gray image2.jpg` (grayscale)

   `convert image1.jpg -separate image2.jpg` (channels)

   `convert image1.jpg -monochrome image2.jpg` (black and white)

Comment: Are bit-map jpeg files widely supported? For example, CMYK jpeg is perfectly cromulent, but some viewers choke or they render improperly.

Comment: You can see the list of image formats by typing `identify -list format`, but as far as I know these files are supported.